# Update fields with an ID that is driven by date range

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables in `SQL`:
T1 is laid out as follows:

```
PrID       NapID       URN       Date
-------------------------------------------
12345   |  NULL    |   123    |  2019-06-02
23456   |  NULL    |   456    |  2019-07-03
34567   |  NULL    |   789    |  2019-07-05
```

T2 is laid out as follows:

```
SYSApID    PnID     StartDate    EndDate
-------------------------------------------
54321   |  2     |  2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30
65432   |  3     |  2019-07-01 | 2019-07-31
```

I'm hoping for a pointer as to how to update the column `NapID` in `table 1`, with with the `SYSApID` from `table 2`, where it will apply the relevant `ID` based on where the `Date` in `table 1` falls between the `StartDate` and `EndDate` in `table2`.

Comment: tag your dbms name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a mixture of previous answers

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET 
    NapID = t2.SYSApID
FROM
    t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.date between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this answer is for SQL SERVER.

```
update t1
set t1.napID = (select top 1 t2.SYSApID from table2 t2 where t1.[Date] between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate)
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
  SET 
      t1.napid = t2.sysapid
FROM t1
     JOIN t2 ON t2.startdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date), 0), 120)
```

Comment: I think you don't need to write `t1` in `t1.napid = t2.sysapid`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, this works in Oracle :-

```
update t1  
set  t1.napID = (select t2.sysappid from t2 where t1.date between t2.start_date and t2.End_date and rownum <2);
```